# Download 8GB data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have around 8GB of data on Firestore. How can I download it. I want to backup it on my Google Drive. If there is any way to do it directly, that'd be great.

Comment: Can this help ? [https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your project's backend with [Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export), you can select the respective project in the top corner as needed. On the left hand side is a `Import/Export` option where you can choose to export all of your database or only partial and follow the prompts.

This does affect your project's usage however as 1 read still counts as 1 read.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data

Answer (score 0):

1. GOTO https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/
2. choose import export
3. choose your project from the status bar
4. make sure billing is enabled
5. Download the data